# Setting up Git Server: Why is access denied while setting variables using Powershell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I'm trying to set up a local Git server on Windows the way it is described on this website: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Setting-up-a-Git-server-on-Windows-using-Git-for-Windows-and-Win32_OpenSSH. When I try to set the variable `$machinePath` (`$machinePath = ${C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin}::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'MACHINE')`) I get an error message telling me that accessing the path `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin` was denied. I do run PowerShell as Administrator. Can anyone tell me how to fix that?

Comment: Where the notation `${C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin}` comes from, and what do you think it means?

Comment: PowerShell told me I should try and use it instead of declaring the location as a String, because that didn't work. I thought the location was what is meant with "[Environment]", because of the declaration of $env stores the path to the location. But maybe, that's exactly what I don't understand...

Comment: Read and _follow_ the code snippet suggested in your link…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step of your linked guide says to run **these** commands to add git to your PATH globally. There's no reason to change them unless you installed git somewhere else:

```
$gitPath = Join-Path -Path $env:ProgramFiles -ChildPath "git\mingw64\bin"
$machinePath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'MACHINE')
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', "$gitPath;$machinePath", 'Machine')
```

Note that setting machine-level environment variables **does** require running-as-administrator.

---

As for powershell syntax:

```
# accessing a class's member method/property is done via 
[ClassName]::Method('parameter1','p2')

# curly brackets are usually script blocks or hash tables
$sciptblock = { ping localhost }
$hashtable = @{ key1 = 'value1'; key2 = 'value2'}

# they can also be used to set a variable name with spaces:
${a b c} = 'abc'

# BUT if you have a file path, powershell will GET/SET the data of the file:
${c:\temp\test.txt} = 'test file'
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have taken a look on how to use powershell before trying to do so...